# How to make my player face cursor even when I am rotating around the player?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make the player face the cursor in a 3d game, to do so I added this code to the player

```
void Update()
{
    Vector3 objectPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

    mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
    mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

    float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 90- angle, 0));

}
```

This works when the camera is facing the player but as I turn around the player it does not follow the cursor anymore. When I stop (for example the camera now is behind the player or at the left) the player rotates facing the wrong position.

Comment: the cursor    is basically a position on your screen ... when you move / rotate the camera so does this point .... what exactly would you expect to happen / where should your player look to if the camera is not facing the player ?

Comment: It isn't very clear, are you applying this code to a 3d game?

Comment: @derHugo if the camera is not facing the player I want the player to face the cursor. because the problem is let's say I rotate the camera around the player and now it is behind the player if I place the mouse cursor  in front of the player, the player turns to the opposite direction  but if my camera is facing the player, the player points to the mouse cursor

Comment: @Voidsay yes it is a 3D game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Solution was that I needed to add the Camera angle of the y axe to the 90 deg offset like so :

```
transform.rotation =  Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, (cam.transform.eulerAngles.y+90)-angle, 0)) ;
```

now the player is always facing the cursor even when I turn around the player

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the cameras rotation to the calculation of the final rotation.

```csharp
[SerializeField] Camera cam;
[SerializeField] Vector3 rotOffset;

void Update()
{
  Vector3 objectPos = cam.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);
  Vector2 mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
  mousePos.x = mousePos.x - objectPos.x;
  mousePos.y = mousePos.y - objectPos.y;

  float angle = Mathf.Atan2(mousePos.y, mousePos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

  transform.rotation = cam.transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle)) * Quaternion.Euler(rotOffset);
}
```

I've extracted your initial rotation offset into a separate variable. You might have to play with it to get the orientation right again and probably change the axis that `angle` is affecting.
Also take note that Quaternion multiplication takes order of operation into account. Only switch it if the rotation is completely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your response but this did not work, the player was rotating in all directions even when I played with the offset it did not help but based on your answer I found a solution that fixed my problem you can find it below